# Passing android Bitmap Data within activity using Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I hava a Bitmap variable named `bmp` in Activity1 , and I want to send the bitmap to Activity2

Following is the code I use to pass it with the intent.

```
Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
in1.putExtra("image",bmp);
startActivity(in1);
```

And in Activity2 I try to access the bitmap using the following code

```
Bundle ex = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp2 = ex.getParceable("image");
ImageView result = (ImageView)findViewById(R.Id.imageView1);
result.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

The application runs without an exception but it does not give the expected result

Comment: This is not a copy of your code, as I see at least two typo's.

Comment: @Christine : this is realy my code hehe,,, but i had it from many tutorial... XP

Comment: So how come you create a Bitmap bmp2, and you set it with setImageBitmap(bmp)? And surely, R.Id.imageView1 does not work. It should be R.id.imageView1.

Comment: You could of course write the bitmap to a file, and read this file in the second activity. You can use the same file to make sure the image remains if the device is rotated.

Comment: Before posting a question, make sure you understand the code you are posting, a plain copy-paste from StackOverflow to fix a bug is useless.. @Christine - I was about to comment the same thing about typos..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Convert it to a Byte array before you add it to the intent, send it out, and decode.

```
//Convert to byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
in1.putExtra("image",byteArray);
```

Then in Activity 2:

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

---

**edit**

Thought I should update this with best practice:

In your first activity, you should save the Bitmap to disk then load it up in the next activity. Make sure to recycle your bitmap in the first activity to prime it for garbage collection:

Activity 1:

```
try {
    //Write file
    String filename = "bitmap.png";
    FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    
    //Cleanup
    stream.close();
    bmp.recycle();

    //Pop intent
    Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    in1.putExtra("image", filename);
    startActivity(in1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In Activity 2, load up the bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
try {
    FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This solved a issue I had. An exception was thrown because "transactionTooLargeException". When sending over extra a full bitmap.

Comment: just wondering how i would use the getIntent() in a Fragment? i have read that it is not possible, but there must be a way.

Comment: getActivity().getIntent()

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't understand why writing the bitmap to a file and reading it later is better than sending a byteArray?

Comment: bytearray = 3 images in memory (bmp first, bytearray, bmp second)
file = 2 images in memory (bmp first, file, bmp third)

Comment: You could just make the byteArray static so the Garbage Collector wouldnt delete it. Dont have to save it locally actually

Comment: I highly suggest avoid using byte array because you can reach the 2MB limit and have a leak. I suggest create a temp file and handle its path through the activities

Comment: @Hareesh sweet! open to anything better if you guys find it!

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes, the bitmap might be too large for encode&decode or pass as a byte array in the intent. This can cause either OOM or a bad UI experience.

I suggest to consider putting the bitmap into a static variable of the new activity (the one that  uses it) which will carefully be null when you no longer need it (meaning in onDestroy but only if "isChangingConfigurations" returns false).

Answer (score 4):

Simply we can pass only Uri of the Bitmap instead of passing Bitmap object. If Bitmap object is Big, that will cause memory issue.

FirstActivity.

```
intent.putExtra("uri", Uri);
```

From SecondActivity we get back bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),Uri.parse(uri));
```

Comment: IOexception when I pass image path in uri . What could be the possible reason.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin Code for send Bitmap to another activity by intent:

1- in First Activity :

```
          val i = Intent(this@Act1, Act2::class.java)
           var bStream  =  ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bStream)
            val byteArray = bStream.toByteArray()
            i.putExtra("image", byteArray )
            startActivity(i)
```

2- In Activity two (Read the bitmap image) :

```
 var bitmap : Bitmap? =null
    if (intent.hasExtra("image")){
      //convert to bitmap          
        val byteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("image")
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
    }
```

3- if you need to set it as background for a view, like ConstraintLayout or... :

```
 if (bitmap != null) {
     //Convert bitmap to BitmapDrawable
     var bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable( resources , bitmap)
      root_constraintLayout.backgroundDrawable = bitmapDrawable
   }
```

Comment: Google just announced they are stopping Kotlin development due to lack of user adaption

Answer (score 1):

create a singleton class for storing bitmap data

```
public final class BitmapData {
    private static final BitmapData bitmapData = new BitmapData();
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private BitmapData() {
    }

    public static BitmapData getInstance() {
        return bitmapData;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
```

in first activity you can set like this.

```
BitmapData.getInstance().setBitmap(bitmap);
```

and in second activity

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapData.getInstance().getBitmap();
```

Note: check null value

Comment: class BitmapData private constructor() {
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

    companion object {
        val instance = BitmapData()
    }
}

Kotlin version of above code. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve this without passing data through intent. Just store the image in the memory and in the next Activity just load the image from that location, which can also avoid app crash from passing large bitmap data.
Note: You need not even pass the location path to the intent, remember the path and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to also post a best practices answer for those looking to do this (but may be asking the wrong question).

Instead of passing a bitmap around (which I presume you downloaded from the network, otherwise, you would already have a file reference to it), I recommend using an image loader such as [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to download an image into an ImageView. You can configure it to then cache the image to disk:

```
 DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Now, just pass the image URL in your intent and use the UIL to load the image. In your newly created activity for example, the image will load instantly because it is loading from the cache - even if your image URL has expired since the download.

Answer (score -7):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("Image", Bitmap);
mIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: Bitmap is not serializable!

Comment: please check this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871482/serializing-and-de-serializing-android-graphics-bitmap-in-java