# Capture Screen Programmatically not working

Tags: android, screenshot, android-screen

I have following method to Capture Screen on Action Item Click. Its working on Android <2.3 but not on 4+. What is wrong with this way of screen capture.

```
private void captureScreen() {
    View v = mapView.getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap capturedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    if(capturedBitmap != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenCapturedAlertActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("capturedImage", capturedBitmap);
        intent.putExtra("name", location.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Screen Capture Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The ScreenCaputureAlertActivity.java >>>

```
public class ScreenCapturedAlertActivity extends SherlockActivity {

private ImageView capturedImage;
private Bitmap capturedBitmap;
private String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screencaptured_alert);

    capturedBitmap = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("capturedImage");
    name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

    capturedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCapturedImage);
    capturedImage.setImageBitmap(capturedBitmap);
}

private void saveAndShare(boolean share) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File dir = new File(root + "/capture/");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    File file = new File(dir, "Capture "+n+".jpg");
    if(file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        capturedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Save Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Save Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if(share) {
        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Location of " + name);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getText(R.string.screen_share_message));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getText(R.string.screen_share_message));
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Save Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        finish();
    }
}

public void saveCapture(View view) {
    saveAndShare(false);
}

public void shareCapture(View view) {
    saveAndShare(true);
}
```

}

Comment: seems ScreenCapturedAlertActivity is not part of SDK. please provide source code this .

Comment: @ShailendraRajawat have a look on the source code.It is just an activity to get the Bitmap and show it in a Alert Fashion. Everything is fine on Android 2.3 but does not works in 4 and 4+

Comment: So, you are getting a blank image? Or any errors?

Comment: @KumarBibek no error messages and no images too :(

Comment: You are passing the whole bitmap to the next activity!! Try writing that bitmap to a file and see if you are getting the bitmap or not.

Comment: @KumarBibek; yes its being saved in SD Card. so what should I do now?

Comment: Can you pull out that file onto your desktop and see if you can open it in any image viewer?

Comment: @KumarBibek yes i did it in the Galaxy SII itself .. just the bitmap is not passed to the ScreenCaptureAlertActivity :( the picture is saved finely in device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @KumarBibek guidance.

The error I was getting was

```
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

So as from the selected answer from the link

[Send Bitmap as Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android)

I did like this in first activity:

```
private void captureScreen() {
    View v = mapView.getRootView();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap capturedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    capturedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    if(capturedBitmap != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenCapturedAlertActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("capture", byteArray);
        intent.putExtra("name", location.getName());
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Screen Capture Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

And in ScreenCapturedAlertActivity :

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("capture");
        capturedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

It is working WELL now. Thanks again to @KumarBibek

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the whole bitmap, try passing the file saved file's path to the next activity. Bitmap is a large object, and it's not supposed to be passed around like that.

Since you already checked the the image is being saved fine, if you deal with paths instead of bitmaps, I think it would solve your problem.