# How to get image from scanned QR image

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am using Zxing library to get QR code from QR image. I can get QR code after scanning image. I want to get the image as bitmap with its code/information also. How can I achieve this?

I open the scan activity, calling like:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I tried to explore the **CaptureActivity** which is inside the Zxing library. I found the handleDecodeExternally method . It has a parameter **Bitmap barcode**. Does this parameter contains scanned picture bitmap? If yes, then I have to send this with Intent when leaving the CaptureActivity?

**Edited and updated**:  After I edited below method on **CaptureActivity**

```
handleDecodeExternally(Result rawResult,
        ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode)
```

and send **Bitmap barcode** to my activity via **Intent** I found the bitmap which is total camera view on scanning mode. Not the QR Image. So, I can't found to get the QR image what I scanned .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ZXing doesn't return bitmap by default in its bundle, a good solution would be to git a version of the source code, and store the bitmap `CaptureActivity.handleDecode` seems to be the right place to save the bitmap or pass it to your calling activity.

here is a tutorial on how to integrate ZXing in your app:
[ZXing tutorial](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) 
and here is link [To ZXing project on google code](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: Actually i need the Qr Image. i have to send bitmap from capture activity to my activity? please explain more.

Comment: just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android question & answer?

Comment: can't get the solution after pass the bitmap of handleDecodeExternally
& get it from my activity. @Mr.Me