# Setting image view background to bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, android-activity, bitmap, imageview

Ive been looking around but couldn't find the solution to my problem. Im am trying to pass the bmp1 to the second activity, Profile. The code pasted does not work, anyone with possible suggestions would be great.
Here is my code for the first part

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions); 
int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)dh); 
int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)dw); 
            if (heightRatio > 1 && widthRatio > 1) 
            { 
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio) { 
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
            } else {
bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                }
            }
bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false; 
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions); 
Bitmap alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(),bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap); 
Paint paint = new Paint();

Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
matrix.setValues(new float[] {
.5f, 0, 0, 

0, .5f, 0, 

0, 0, 1
 });

canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
ImageView alteredImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.AlteredImageView); 
alteredImageView.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);

    chosenImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp1); 
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  Log.v("ERROR",e.toString());

 }
        }
        Nex.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Choose.this, Profile.class);
                 // your bitmap
                ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
                intent.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
                intent.putExtra("location", textView1.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        );

    }
}


public class Profile extends Activity {
    ImageView picture;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Picture);


        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bytearray");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to think this much..
take one static Bitmap in Choose Activity and use it in Profile Activity.
Hope this will help you to understand:

```
Choose.java
    static Bitmap bit=null;
  //then assign bitmap when it available
   bit=bmp1 //this is your bitmap

 //now at Profile.java use Choose.bit
   if(Choose.bit!=null)
 {
     profimageview.setBitmap(Choose.bit); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bmp1);
```

and

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

Comment: in the profile class, Im getting an error on the "intent", do you know  why that may be the case?

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code. you are using String "byteArray" as Key for putting byte array but retrieving in Profile Activity with different String Key "Image"

Comment: see JRowan answer. it looks fine