# Implementing fix on Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-image

In my widget, I have an imageView that collect an image from the user gallery and then sets that image up as the background in another activity. It works fine, but when I try to add an image file that is too big (such as an image from the camera) or upload many image files, I get an "out of memory" error. After looking around stackoverflow for a while, I noticed that everyone pretty much used the basic method of:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampleImage(File f, int width, int height) {
try {
    System.gc(); // First of all free some memory

    // Decode image size

    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to

    final int requiredWidth = width;
    final int requiredHeight = height;

    // Find the scale value (as a power of 2)

    int sampleScaleSize = 1;

    while (o.outWidth / sampleScaleSize / 2 >= requiredWidth && o.outHeight / sampleScaleSize / 2 >= requiredHeight)
        sampleScaleSize *= 2;

    // Decode with inSampleSize

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = sampleScaleSize;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage()); // We don't want the application to just throw an exception
}

return null;
}
```

I also noticed that people have recycled unused bitmaps as well. I understand how this works but I don't know where I should put it in my coding.

Here are my two classes (Personalize.java where the imageView to collect the background is. It has the imageView and two buttons (one for choosing an image from the gallery where it then displays that image into the imageView and the other to then set that image as the background).

First here is Personalize.java:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Personalize extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button;
ImageView image; //the imageview for setting the background
ImageView image2; //the imageview for setting the icon (not focusing on)
Button btnChangeImage;
Button btnChangeImageForIcon;
Button btnSetBackground;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_2 = 2;
private String  selectedImagePath;
Bitmap background;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Icon);

Button btnChangeImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);    
btnChangeImage.setOnClickListener(this);
Button btnChangeImageForIcon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImageForIcon); 
btnChangeImageForIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
Button btnSetBackground = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetBackground);
btnSetBackground.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
switch (v.getId()) { 
case R.id.btnChangeImage: 
launchImageChooser(); 
break; 
case R.id.btnChangeImageForIcon: 
launchImageChooser(); 
break; 
case R.id.btnSetBackground: 
setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop(); 
break; 
} 
} 

private void setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop() {
Log.d("Personalize", "setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop() called");
Intent i = getIntent();
//Convert bitmap to byte array to send back to activity
// See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
background.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[]byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

i.putExtra("myBackgroundBitmap", byteArray);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
}

private void launchImageChooser() {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
if(cursor != null) {
cursor.close();
}
return imagePath;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    background = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(background != null){
        image.setImageBitmap(background); 
    }           
} else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_2)
{
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
    Bitmap b2 = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(b2 != null){
        image2.setImageBitmap(b2);
    }
}    
}
}

private Bitmap getAndDecodeImage(String  selectedImagePath){
try {
    Log.d("Personalize", "selectedImagePath: " + selectedImagePath);
    FileInputStream fileis=new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
    BufferedInputStream bufferedstream=new BufferedInputStream(fileis);
    byte[] bMapArray= new byte[bufferedstream.available()];
    bufferedstream.read(bMapArray);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);

    if (fileis != null) 
    {
        fileis.close();
    }
    if (bufferedstream != null) 
    {
        bufferedstream.close();
    }
    return bMap;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {                   
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
return null;
}


public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png",     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.close();   
      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   return false;
   }
}

}
```

Then here is my Drag_and_Drop_App.java (snippet of important parts -- collects bitmap and sets as background):

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Drag_and_Drop_App extends Activity {
private static final int SET_BACKGROUND = 10;

private ListView mListAppInfo;
// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;
public AppInfoAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set layout for the main screen
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);

    // import buttons
    Button btnLinkToFeedback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToFeedback);
    Button btnLinkToPersonalize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToPersonalize);


    // Link to Personalize Screen
    btnLinkToPersonalize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Personalize.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, SET_BACKGROUND);

        }
    });

}
public Bitmap getThumbnail(String filename) { 
     Bitmap thumbnail = null; 
     try { 
     File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename); 
     FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath); 
     thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi); 
     } catch (Exception ex) { 
     Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage()); 
     } 
     return thumbnail; 
     } 

     @Override 
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
     Log.i("Drag_and_Drop_App", "requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode); 
     if(requestCode == SET_BACKGROUND && resultCode == RESULT_OK){ 
     byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("myBackgroundBitmap"); 
     Bitmap myBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length); 
     setBackgroundImage(myBackground); 
     } 
     } 

     @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
     private void setBackgroundImage(Bitmap bitmap) { 
     RelativeLayout yourBackgroundView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_drag_and_drop_app); 

     Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap); 

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) { 
     yourBackgroundView.setBackgroundDrawable(d); 
     } else { 
     yourBackgroundView.setBackground(d); 
     } 
     } 

     }
```

So where could I implement that coding and where could I also get rid of other unused bitmaps in memory? (recycle them?)

Comment: Does it Android Bitmap course? please cut off your code and leave only relevant part. Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()

Comment: too long, didn't read.

Comment: @alex I trimmed it up a little

Comment: @piotrpo thanks for the link but I'm also wondering where I could implement the recycle into my coding