# Image Paths are not saved with Shared Preferences to keep Image

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I am trying to save the image Path from user selected images so that when the user exits and reopens the app, the image is still set as either the background or in an imageView for the icon (they both use the same image Path method)

Here is my coding (Drag_and_Drop_App.java):

```
public Bitmap getThumbnail(String filename) { 
     Bitmap thumbnail = null; 
     try { 
     File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename); 
     FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath); 
     thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi); 
     } catch (Exception ex) { 
     Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage()); 
     } 
     return thumbnail; 
     } 

     @Override 
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
     Log.i("Drag_and_Drop_App", "requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode); 
     if(requestCode == SET_BACKGROUND && resultCode == RESULT_OK){ 
     byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("myBackgroundBitmap"); 
     Bitmap myBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length); 
     setBackgroundImage(myBackground); 
     } 
     else if(requestCode == RESULT_ICON){
         byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("myIconBitmap"); 
         Bitmap myIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length); 
         setBackgroundImageForIcon(myIcon); 
         Log.d("Drag_and_Drop_App", "Icon is set");
     }
     }
```

Personalize.java:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
if(cursor != null) {
cursor.close();
}
return imagePath;
}

private void setIconImageInWidget() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("Personalize", "setIconImageInWidget() called");
Intent i = getIntent();
//Convert bitmap to byte array to send back to activity
// See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android
scaleDownBitmapForIcon(b2, 500, this.getBaseContext());
Log.d("Personalize", "Scale Bitmap Chosen For Icon");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[]byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

i.putExtra("myIconBitmap", byteArray);
setResult(RESULT_ICON, i);
finish();
}

private void setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop() {
Log.d("Personalize", "setBackgroundImageInDragAndDrop() called");
Intent i = getIntent();
//Convert bitmap to byte array to send back to activity
// See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android
scaleDownBitmap(background, 500, this.getBaseContext());
Log.d("Personalize", "Scale Bitmap Chosen");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
background.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[]byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

i.putExtra("myBackgroundBitmap", byteArray);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
}

@Override
 protected void onPause() {
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1); //open shared preferences with name AppSharedPref
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("ImagePath", selectedImagePath); //Store selectedImagePath with key "ImagePath". This key will be then used to retrieve data.
editor.commit();
super.onPause();
Log.d("Personalize", "onPause() called and selectedImagePath saved");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1);
selectedImagePath = sp.getString("ImagePath", "");
super.onResume();
Log.d("Personalize", "onResume() called and images uploaded");
}

public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
   try {
      FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.close();   
      return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   return false;
   }
}
```

The issue is that this doesn't work and when I reopen the app, the background is not set with the before selected image.

Comment: i would rather prefer to store the image in a file and retrieve it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u are fetching image path from sharedpref onResume(), Try to add that image as background if selectedPath is not null.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1);
selectedImagePath = sp.getString("ImagePath", "");
super.onResume();
Log.d("Personalize", "onResume() called and images uploaded");
Log.d("Personalize", "Now set the image as background");
 background = getAndDecodeImage(selectedImagePath);
    if(background != null){
        image.setImageBitmap(background); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: I can also add another if statement like this `if(b2 != null){
            image2.setImageBitmap(b2);
        }` for my other imageView right?

Comment: Yes u can.Tey to set your preference when u get the selected imagepath instead of setting it on onPause().

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple App on [Github](https://github.com/martinsing/ImageSaveAndRetrieve) to demonstrate this idea, if you want to follow:

#### 1. Declare the variables:

```
private ImageView mImage;
private Uri mImageUri;
```

#### 2. Select the image:

```
public void imageSelect() {
     Intent intent;
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     } else {
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     }
     intent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
         PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
 }
```

#### 3. Save the image URI:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // Check which request we're responding to
     if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
         // Make sure the request was successful
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             // The user picked a image.
             // The Intent's data Uri identifies which item was selected.
            if (data != null) {

                // This is the key line item, URI specifies the name of the data
                mImageUri = data.getData();

                // Saves image URI as string to Default Shared Preferences
                SharedPreferences preferences = 
                     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageUri));
                editor.commit();

                // Sets the ImageView with the Image URI
                mImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
                mImage.invalidate();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

#### 4. Retrieve the image URI in onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);

    if (mImageUri != null) {
        mImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
    } else {
        // uses a default image
        mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
```

**That's it!** Now when the user exits and reopens the app, the image is still set as an imageView.