# Activity not starting when send Bitmap through intent

Tags: android

In my app, I am starting an Activity for current Activity and sending Bitmap through Intent but Activity will not start and when I am not sending that Bitmap it is working fine. Here is the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("USERNAME", userName);
i.putExtra("STATUS", status);
i.putExtra("IMAGE_BITMAP", bitmap);
startActivity(i);
```

When is execute this code activity B is not starting but when i remove `i.putExtra("IMAGE_BITMAP", bitmap);` this line, it works fine. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it giving any errors?

Comment: No, its not giving any error. It execute all

Comment: So B is not coming on front?

Comment: Yes B is not coming on front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert it to a Byte array before you add it to the intent. Here is the example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010565/655987

**Update:** I was using the method above but the following might be easier to use I guess

[How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another/2459624#2459624)

**Update2:** Please look at this comment, too. This additional one is not a solution to your problem, but just a friendly reminder

[How can I pass a Bitmap object from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another/2459624#comment9650501_2459624)

Comment: I am working same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another/2459624#2459624 still its not woking.

Comment: Could you try the first one? I got it to run sooo many times.

Comment: Thanks first one is working fine... but want to know why second one is not working?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know Bitmap is 'Parcelable' before and now I'm curious too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `public static` global variable for that. Try this

Create one class

```
public class Constant  {
  public static Bitmap b = null;
}
```

Now when you want to send Bitmap from one activity to other, use it as below.

In first activity,

```
Constant.b = bitmap;
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("USERNAME", userName);
i.putExtra("STATUS", status);
startActivity(i);
```

In second activity.

```
Bitmap b = Constant.b;
img.setImageBitmap(b);  //just for example, use it as per your requirement
```