# Android - getIntent() from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am trying to pass a bitmap from one fragment to another--and am using this post as a guide:

[send Bitmap using intent Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android)

What i am having trouble with is in the receiving activity fragment using getIntent(). It doesn't recognize the method. there are some posts out there saying that its not possible to use getIntent() in a fragment... but there must be a way? should the code go in the host activity?

here is what i am trying:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
    try {
        FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
        imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use a `getIntent()` with `Fragments` but you need to call `getActivity()` first. Something like `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("image")` could work.

Answer (score 8):

You can also achieve this with `Fragment` using `setArguments()` and `getArguments()`, like the following:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("image", fileName);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);//Here pass your data
```

Now inside your fragment class ,for example inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` do the following:

```
String fileName = this.getArguments().getString("image");
```

Comment: Yes, its name is Arguments. I will remember it. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's not that you can't pass data, it's that you don't want to.

From the Fragment [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

If you take a look at the `Fragment` documentation, it should walk you through how to do this.

Comment: Gave this an up vote not because it solves the question but is rather the proper approach. You should use the activity as the "medium" for having the fragments communicate with one another.

Answer (score 3):

If you want get intent data, you have to call `Fragment's` method [`getArguments()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()), which returns `Bundle` with extras.

Comment: fragments dont have a getArguments() directly.  They are a property of getActivity()

Answer (score 1):

To get intent extra write this code in fragment

```
if (requireActivity().intent.hasExtra("key_name")) {
    val extra = requireActivity().intent.getStringExtra("key_name")
}
```