# Which method should I use in a fragment when I want to get information from activity different with parent activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment

I have two activities. And I passed the argument to the target activity by intent:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("ImagePath", path);
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("paths", bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

The target activity `DetailActivity` has a fragment, and I want to get the argument `ImagePath` in it. Now I have two method:

1. I get the argument in the `DetailActivity` by `getIntent()` and then pass it to the fragment using `setArgmunets()`
2. I get the argument in the target fragment using `getActivity().getIntent()` directly.

I like the method 2 and use it now because the clean code. But the Android Studio tell me the message `Method invocation 'getIntent' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'` in `getIntent()`.

So should I abandon the method 2?

---

Update: Final, I used the method 1, because of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26939986/4985530) :

> From the Fragment documentation:
>
> > Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Below Code :**

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.BUNDLE_DATA, "From Activity");
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**and in Fragment onCreateView method:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString(Constants.BUNDLE_DATA);    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

If you want to send large data ,then create a model and make that model **implements Serializable** .

Answer (score 1):

You can check for extras..

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();

if(intent.hasExtra("paths")){
  // get the data
}else{
   // Do something else
}
```

Comment: But the warning occurred in `getActivity().getIntent()`， not in `getBundleExtra("paths") `

Comment: You can use context like this ((Activity)context).getIntent();

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not about the intent. It's because in some point of the time(e.g. fragment has been detached from the activity) getActivity() method can return null. So, correct call will be the next:

```
if(getActivity != null) getActivity().getIntent()
```

Comment: Another way: I want to call the parent activity some times likes `getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(...)`. Is this better to define variable in fragment's `onCreate()`: `if (getActivity() != null) mActivity = getActivity();`

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` on Fragment may produce null.

So you need to use either any interface for communication between activity and fragment or use bundle by passing in `setArgument()` in instance of fragment.