# Access array elements by different activities in android

Tags: arrays, android-activity, get, element, public

I am bigginner in android and want to ask. Is there a way to access elements of an array that is declared as public static in different other activities under same package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intent` on accessing value from another class

Class1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassB);
String[] data = new String[] {"value1", "value2"};
intent.putExtra("strings", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Class2:

```
public void onCreate() {
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String[] data = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
}
```

Comment: @Famador what will be the case if array consists of imageviews?

Comment: you can Convert it to a Byte array before you add it to the intent, send it out, and decode. visit this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android