# How to send rotate image to second activity

Tags: android, database, image, rotation, android-recyclerview

I am displaying all image from gallery into recycle view and implement the code to rotate it but I don't know how to send this rotated image to next activity.

Please help me to out this. I am new in android

```
public class UploadQueue extends Activity {

    public QueueAdapter queueAdapter;
    public ArrayList<QueueItem> queueItems = new ArrayList<QueueItem>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.uploadqueue);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final ImageButton btnSelect= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.select);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ArrayList<QueueItem> selected = queueAdapter.getSelected();
                String[] allPath = new String[selected.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < allPath.length; i++) {
                    allPath[i] = selected.get(i).path;
                }

                if (allPath.length <=10)
                {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(UploadQueue.this,ImageGalleryActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("all_path", allPath);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Maximum 10 images share",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        queueAdapter = new QueueAdapter(UploadQueue.this, queueItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(queueAdapter);
        Intent i= getIntent();
        String[] all_path = i.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");
        queueAdapter.initialize(all_path);


    }


    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(false);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
    }


    public class QueueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

        public ArrayList<QueueItem> queueItems;
        public Context context;

        public QueueAdapter(UploadQueue context, ArrayList<QueueItem> queueItems) {
            this.queueItems=queueItems;
            this.context=context;
        }

        public void delete(int position) {

            queueItems.remove(position);
            Log.d("Deny", "" + position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            Log.d("Deny", "" + position);


        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.uploadqueueitem, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
            return viewHolder;

        }

        public ArrayList<QueueItem> getSelected() {
            ArrayList<QueueItem> dataT = new ArrayList<QueueItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < queueItems.size(); i++) {

                    dataT.add(queueItems.get(i));

            }


            return dataT;
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

            QueueItem item = getItem(position);


            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.path);
            viewHolder.imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);

        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return queueItems.size();
        }

        public QueueItem getItem(int position) {
            return queueItems.get(position);
        }

        public void initialize(String[] all_path) {

            queueItems.clear();
            for (String item : all_path) {
              QueueItem queueItem = new QueueItem();
                queueItem.path =item;
                Log.e("UploadQueue Path ", queueItem.path);

                queueItems.add(queueItem);
            }
            Log.e("QueueItem SIze()", "" + queueItems.size());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }

    }


    class QueueItem
    {
        String path;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        public ImageView imageview;
        ImageButton btnLeft,btnRight,btnDelete;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            imageview = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.QueueItemThumbnail);
            btnDelete= (ImageButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            btnLeft= (ImageButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rotateLeft);
            btnRight= (ImageButton) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rotateRight);

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    queueAdapter.delete(getAdapterPosition());
                }

            });

            btnLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.e("POSITIN LEFT ", "" + getAdapterPosition());
                     imageview.setRotation(imageview.getRotation() + 90);


                }
            });

           btnRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   Log.e("POSITIN RIGHT  ", "" + getAdapterPosition());
                    imageview.setRotation(imageview.getRotation() - 90);


                }
            });
        }

    }
```

ImageGalleryActivity class

```
public class ImageGalleryActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        Intent i= getIntent();
        String[] all_path = i.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");
        addImagesToThegallery(all_path);
    }

    private void addImagesToThegallery(String[] all_path) {

        LinearLayout imageGallery = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);
        for(String image : all_path) {
            imageGallery.addView(getImageView(image));
        }

    }

    private View getImageView(String image) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //set images
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to send the image path to next activity and in that activity rotate the images

Comment: Try using intents to pass anythig ftom one activity to another

Comment: you can create bitmap and send it as base64 string from activity

Comment: Can u provide me any link@Ajay

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2459624/3514144 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11010565/3514144

Answer (score 0):

Pass the bitmap via putExtra

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
 startActivity(intent);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: i don't want to rotate in next activity..is it possible to send rotate image..@DroidHacker