# Show selected image in another activity

Tags: java, android, bitmap, resize, uri

I've searched on stackoverflow but never found a solution

Here is my situation:

I have a button which start an intent to pick an image

How can I resize proportionally (to keep the aspect ration) and display it on another activity (in imageview)?

I also want to save this resized image to user storage. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```html
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setType("image/*");
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

             startActivityForResult(
                     Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.completeaction)),
                     PICK_FROM_FILE);         
        }

    });
}
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      Bitmap selectedphoto   = null;

      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == RequestExternal && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

          Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
          String [] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
          Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();   
          int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
          String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
          selectedphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
          cursor.close();
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PhotoResized.class);
          intent.putExtra("data", selectedphoto);
          startActivity(intent);
     }
      }
```

**PhotoResized.java**

```html
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.photoresized);
  img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}
```

Comment: how about some photo cropper?

Comment: No, I want the image to be resized into specific height and width and not cropped

Answer (score 0):

For resizing the image use sampling technique provided by dev.android  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Use Lrucache for storing images. Use technique shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Comment: How can I show the selected image to another activity?

Comment: you will store the image in cache with some key like a hashmap,

Comment: and retrieve the image from Lrucache with that key, let me know if you have any more doubts :)

Comment: Isn't better with getting intent data with uri or sth like that?

Comment: To display the image in the other activity

Comment: you can do that. I personally would not recommend, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android