# android: Send data from an adapter class to Activity

Tags: java, android

Hey there I want to add pictures to favorite activity when a user tap on a picture. So far I'm able to get the data but don't know how to pass it to my favorite activity. How should I approach this problem, perhaps using intent and broadcast? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here's my MyRecyclerAdapter class

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>{

    Context c;
    ArrayList<Album> albums;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Album> albums){
        this.c=c;
        this.albums=albums;
    }
    // Initialize holder
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

       View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
       return holder;
    }

    //Bind data to views
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

      holder.nameTxt.setText(albums.get(position).getName());
      holder.img.setImageResource(albums.get(position).getImage());

     //listener
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
                Toast.makeText(c,albums.get(pos).getName() + " ,added to favorite ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             //  albums.get(pos).getName();

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return albums.size();
    }
}
```

Here's my MyViewHolder class

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageView img;
    TextView nameTxt;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        nameTxt=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic)
    {
        this.itemClickListener=ic;

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,getLayoutPosition());


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to display selected image in the activity where this RecyclerViewAdapter get called?

Comment: If you find the correct Image you want to transfer to your activity, try doing so, that you start a new Intent to switch to FavouriteActivity and passing Extra the image. You have to convert Bitmap into ByteArray to do so. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android) if it helps.

Comment: @AjayShrestha (ah testai vanam). I was thinking to pass just a string value but may be I should pass an bitmap image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your image is located in your drawable folder and can be obtained by this line: `albums.get(position).getImage()`

then just pass the int value to your FavoritesActivity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(c, FavoritesActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, albums.get(pos).getImage());
c.startActivity(intent); // put context infront
```

Note that `albums.get(pos).getImage()` should return and int value.
Then in your FavoritesActivity retrieve by calling the following:

```
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)){
    int image = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    myImageView.setImageResource(image);
}
```

Comment: Okay I was able to pass the data, but how do I save the data? Thanks

Comment: @user7062312 where do you want to save the data?

Comment: I want to save data on my favorite activity. I want to display the images that I passed on using intent. Right now, It is only passing the data.

Comment: @user7062312 ok, if you need to display it in a ImageView then do something similar what you did to display the image in your RecyclerView. I updated the answer. I hope it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried doing this      ImageView displayImage = (ImageView)    findViewById(R.id.favImage);
            int favImage = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,image);
            displayImage.setImageResource(favImage);             But this doesn't not save the image, only displays.

Comment: Okay I got it now

Comment: Okay I just added my recycler view layout but whenever I tap on the image it will only display the image but doesn't  save it in the favorite activity.  Since, I'm using a button( button is in MainActivty) to view favorited images, whenever I clicked the button it shows nothing. Do I need to pass data from recycler to MainActivity and MainActivity to Favorite?

Comment: And by the way this line int image = intent.getIntExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); requires a second argument. I was using image from my other class. May be that's the reason

Comment: @user7062312 you can't save permanent values to an Activity. When you exit your FavoritesActivity, its values are destroyed. If you want to keep track of favorite images then use a database, that way you can see your favorite images even after you close your app.