# How to pass large generated bitmap images between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I get camera frames, do some processing using OpenCV, and generate several Bitmap images. I want to pass them to another activity. Now, these images are not very small. In fact, if I try to pass all of them using `intent.putExtra` as `parcelable`s, I get

```
TransactionTooLargeException
```

In case you ask, these images are not resources. They are purely generated images and are in memory. So there is no URI to find them.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to convert it to byteArray I guess

Comment: Will converting it to byte array prevent TransactionTooLargeException @esQmo_?

Comment: Yes since passing with parcelable would fail because of the size of parcelable (1mb I guess). So there are couple of way to achieve this among those converting to byteArray, saving the bitmap in internal storage, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010565/5374691

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing android Bitmap Data within activity using Intent in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/passing-android-bitmap-data-within-activity-using-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need first to convert it to byteArray

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
i.putExtra("bitmap", byteArray);
startActivity(i);
```

And retrieve it like:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
//...

byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bitmap");
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

You can also read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you save these images to internal memory using `openFileOutput` and pass saved filenames to the next activity where they will be retrieved via `openFileInput`.

Because as @esQmo_ mentioned, bundles are very limited in memory size and are not designed to transfer a large amount of data.