# How to send a Bitmap with Intent from RecyclerView Adapter to Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to send a *Bitmap* with *Intent* from a *RecyclerView* adapter to an *Activity*. The error I get is:
`FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 6010104)`.
Can anyone find what is wrong?  My code is below.

```
class ClothesAdapter(private var clothesList: List<ClothModel>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ClothesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var titleView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title_view)
        var imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view)
    }

    @NonNull
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.cloth_row, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val cloth = clothesList[position]
        holder.titleView.text = cloth.getTitle()
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(cloth.getBitmap())

        var context = holder.itemView.context

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener {

            val clothBitmap = cloth.getBitmap()!!

            val bStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            clothBitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream)
            val byteArray: ByteArray = bStream.toByteArray()
            val intent = Intent(context, StillImageActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("bitmap", byteArray)
            context.startActivity(intent)   //AT THIS POINT I GET ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return clothesList.size
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you do not send Bitmap directly? Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it with the intent.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone find what is wrong?

Most likely [TransactionTooLargeException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException) is the reason.

Instead of putting *ByteArray* to an *Intent*, write it to a file and put the file *URI* to the *Intent*. Later in the *Activity* read the *ByteArray* from the file using the *URI* passed.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11010386/3290339) on how it's done.