# Getting Error Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x09050941 (code=1) On Using Canvas for round Image

Tags: android, sqlite, canvas, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am stuck with one strange issue.
In my app, user is able to change his/her profile picture. And that image is shown in one round.
I am taking image from camera/file (Gallery) & to covert the bitmap in round corner I am using following code.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedShape(Context context, Bitmap scaleBitmapImage, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
        int targetWidth = getDPEquivalentPixels(context, imageWidth);
        int targetHeight = getDPEquivalentPixels(context, imageHeight);
        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2, ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2, (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2), Path.Direction.CW);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        // paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), paint);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
        return targetBitmap;
    }
```

First I am uploading the Image to server compressing it. Then I save it in local SQLite  as byte array & convert it into round bitmap using above method to show on `ImageView`.

Now from now onward I will refer the `SQLite` for profile image. My problem is for first time the round corner code is working fine but then when I use with SQLIte Image & try to convert it into round shape I am getting following error.

```
A/libc(14809): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5f763ee0 (code=1), thread 14809
```

EDIT ::

I am having the User POJO which saves the User object retrived from SQLite. And I am converting this Pojo into json & storing in SharedPreferance till the time User session in active.

```
public class User {

    private int uid;
    private String userName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Date dob;
    private String gender;
    private int delFlag;
    private int pin;
    private Bitmap imageData;

}
```

I am using Gson for JSON to POJO & vice-verse parsing. But I don't know whether the Gson library would parse my `imageData` (Data type Bitmap) properly or not. It might be creating problem.

Comment: I can see that it is in libc, but usually if you see the whole dump in LogCat, you can tell what c code and what java it was in just before the crash?

Comment: You could be dereferencing a null pointer in native code. I would check really carefully if you aren't passing any null references back to the bitmap converter. Just debug it line by line.

Comment: @hack_on - In LogCat, I am seeing only this line. other logs are just usual what I get in normal execution.

Comment: OK, like edward said, comment out this method one line at a time until it stops crashing.  To my eyes it all looks fine.  I have seen some posts where some other code had previously passed a null down to the bitmap methods and then it blew up in a completely different piece of code.  You have checked that the profile image coming back from SQLite is not null?

Comment: As per Edvard's suggestion, I put null checks wherever I am using Bitmap for profile pic. I tried debugging the app, it is hanging & then gives above error. But I have one doubt. Please check `EDIT` in my question.

Comment: Thanks @Edward van Raak. You were right about the cause of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will want to check [this guys solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871482/serializing-and-de-serializing-android-graphics-bitmap-in-java) as it seems that Bitmap is not serializable.  I don't know enough about the mechanics of JSON/Gson to know that this is definitely the problem.  If I were in your shoes I would first change the code so that it reads the bitmap from a PNG file instead of the JSON, and confirm that this is *the* issue.  Then look at a better way to serialize/store the bitmap like the link above.

Comment: Yes you are right. The `Bitmap` or `Byte Array` is not serialized through `Gson`. I declared my `Bitmap` as `transient`. Thus avoiding it from serialization. And whenever I need the image I simply query the `SQLite`. I am sure I was getting error because Bitmap conversion might be receiving null values. Thanks.