# How to Pass NameValuePair Object of ArrayList one Activity to another Activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to pass arrylist of NameValuePair one activity to another acivity,I searched so much for this ,i found similar questions But i am unable to get Answer,I tried but i am getting exception 
,Please anybody tell me how to pass

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevlaList= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    namevlaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formal_name",mLegalName));
    namevlaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_phone_no",mPhno));
    namevlaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",mEmail));
    namevlaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact_name",mContactName));
    namevlaList.add(new            
    BasicNameValuePair("contact_number",mContactNumber));
    namevlaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",mPwd));  
    Intent intent = new 
    Intent(this,Second.class);
    intent.putExtra("extra", namevlaList);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("namevlaList", namevlaList);

Comment: how to get that value in second activty?

Comment: namevlaList= (ArrayList ) getArguments().get("namevlaList");

Comment: hope it helps, i have answered below too

Comment: namevlaList= (ArrayList ) getIntent().getExtra().get("namevlaList");

Answer (score 0):

You can pass using `Bundle`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Second.class);
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putSerializable("extra",  namevlaList.toArray());// cast to array and put
intent .putExtras(extra);
startActivity(intent);
```

and on Second Activity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
List<NameValuePair> Namevaluepairvariable = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
Namevaluepairvariable =  (List<NameValuePair>) extras.getSerializable("extra");
```

use  `implements Serializable` for your Second Activity

Comment: how to get that value in another activity?

Comment: I am getting exception when getting value in second activity java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value formal_name=fhjj

Comment: use  `implements Serializable` for your Second Activity

Comment: I have implements Serializable for my Second Activity But i am getting same Exception

Comment: is it same exception ??  can you show your second activity code

Comment: ya same Intent i = getIntent();
  Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
  List<NameValuePair> Namevaluepairvariable = (List<NameValuePair>) extras.getSerializable("namevlaList");

Comment: and DriverSetupSecondActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,Serializable

Comment: No I did but getting same Exception

Comment: try with this line `extra.putSerializable("extra",  namevlaList.toArray());`  and also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18050203/2811956

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this, hope it helps

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Second.class);
intent.putExtra("namevlaList", namevlaList);
startActivity(intent);
```

in next activity use this

```
// initialize array list in onCreate
namevlaList= (ArrayList) getIntent().getExtra().get("namevlaList");
```

also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another)

this is because BasicNameValuePair is not serializable see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050030/intent-putextra-arraylistnamevaluepair) hope it helps

Comment: try this getInent().getExtra() if you are in activity

Comment: ya i tried    but 
I am getting exception when getting value in second activity java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value formal_name=fhjj

Comment: answer is edited hope it works, ask me if there is any other problem you face

Comment: I did but getting same Exception

Comment: this is because BasicNameValuePair is not serializable see this hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050030/intent-putextra-arraylistnamevaluepair

Comment: did it helped? or you still facing the problem?

Comment: No I am Still facing problem

Comment: I am unbale to implement in my application