# Pass multidimensional ArrayList of LatLng through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>` from one intent to another using `putParcelableArrayListExtra ()` but for some reason it doesn't like my list. I define the array list with `ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> listOfStrokes = new ArrayList<>();` and I am trying to pass it with

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> listOfStrokes = new ArrayList<>();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateFarm.class);

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listOfStrokes", listOfStrokes);
```

but I am getting a

> Error:(383, 65) error: incompatible types: ArrayList> cannot be converted to ArrayList

error. Is there a way to pass this  object?

Comment: What is this listOfStrokes magic you speak of?

Comment: It is my multidimensional ArrayList. I'll reformat my question to make that more clear

Comment: Shouldn't it be like ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> listOfStrokes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLang>(); .. Android ain't Java8, you have to specify the complete names...

Comment: When I put that Android Studio gives me a warning that it is redundant and that it doesn't need to be there. I can add to the list no problem it is just passing it

Comment: Your `LatLng` might have to implement `Parcelable`.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050030/intent-putextra-arraylistnamevaluepair

Comment: Try it out..lemme know...

Comment: Making it `new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>()` makes no difference

Comment: putParcelableArrayListExtra expects an array list of ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>  object but your giving it an Arraylist of ArrayList of ArrayList does not implement Parcelable.  can you just try putExtra?  That will take an arraylist of arraylist.

Comment: yep - just tested this - see answer below

Answer (score 0):

First - consider using Guava tables to avoid a List of Lists pattern.

putParcelableArrayListExtra expects a List of objects that implements Parcelable. ArrayList does not. Arraylist implements Serializable, so the below will work.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> listOfStrokes = new ArrayList<>();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateFarm.class);

intent.putExtra("listOfStrokes", listOfStrokes);
```