# Passing an array of GeoCodes from 1 intent to another

Tags: android, android-intent, geolocation

Just wondering what the best way to pass an array list of GeoCodes is?

I can seem to put the arraylist into the intent okay using

```
saveRouteIntent.putExtra("waypoints", waypoints);
```

But I cant see how I would get the list in the new activity.

I could build two double arraylists and pass them across and then create the geocode array list again on the other side but im assuming there is a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `serializable` while passing data through `putExtra()`

First Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> waypoints= new ArrayList<String>();
saveRouteIntent.putExtra("waypoints", waypoints);
```

In the other Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("waypoints");
```

Comment: That done the trick, thanks. Can you tell me though is there a performance hit for long arrays?

Answer (score 0):

If its an array you can use `serializable` to `putExtra()` , but in this case you'll have to implement your own subclass that extends `BasicNameValuePair` , for a perfect implementation [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050030/intent-putextra-arraylistnamevaluepair).