# How does Bitmap compress work in android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, save

I have kind of a general question.
I am writing a logging app where the user can choose to take a picture and save it along with other information. All of the information is stored as an object in an arraylist, but i've had a hard time saving the image to file as part of the object. I finally figured out that Bitmap is not serializable, so that's where one problem was. By now all I want to do is save the bitmap in its own arraylist so that I can call a specific bitmap using the same position as I would for the object arraylist, and I can set the bitmap on an ImageViewer. 
In all of my findings for saving Bitmaps i saw that everyone is compressing them and decoding them. My question is, why does a bitmap have to be compressed (or does it) to be saved to file?

Just in case this will help my question make more sense, here is my code:

```
package com.example.ticklist;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class DataProvider {

    private static final String ROUTES = "routes";
    private static final String PICS = "pictures";
    static Bitmap photo;
    static ArrayList<Bitmap> bList;

    public static boolean writeRoute(Route r, Bitmap img){
        ArrayList<Route> list = getRoutes();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bmlist = getPictures();
        list.add(r);
        bmlist.add(img);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        FileOutputStream fosp;
        try {
            fos = TicklistMain.getContext().openFileOutput(ROUTES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            fosp = TicklistMain.getContext().openFileOutput(PICS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oosp = new ObjectOutputStream(fosp);
            oos.writeObject(list);
            oosp.writeObject(bmlist);
            oos.close();
            oosp.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Route> getRoutes(){
        FileInputStream fis;
        ArrayList<Route> list = null;
        try {
            fis = TicklistMain.getContext().openFileInput(ROUTES);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            list = (ArrayList<Route>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            list = new ArrayList<Route>();

        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            list = new ArrayList<Route>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            list = new ArrayList<Route>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            list = new ArrayList<Route>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Bitmap> getPictures(){
        FileInputStream fis;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bmlist = null;
        try {
            fis = TicklistMain.getContext().openFileInput(PICS);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            bmlist = (ArrayList<Bitmap>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            bmlist = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            bmlist = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            bmlist = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            bmlist = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmlist;
    }
    public static Bitmap getPicture(int position){
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bList = getPictures();
        photo = bList.get(position);
        return photo;
    }

}
```

and where I'm calling it:

```
package com.example.ticklist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendList extends ListFragment {

    AddRope ar = new AddRope();
    Bitmap bm;
    private static final String TAG = TicklistMain.class.getName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView( inflater,  container, savedInstanceState);
        //View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.mylistfrag_layout, container, false);
        //return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b) {
        super.onActivityCreated(b);
        ArrayList<Route> list = DataProvider.getRoutes();
        ArrayAdapter<Route> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Route>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    } //onActivity

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ArrayList<Route> list = DataProvider.getRoutes();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> pList = DataProvider.getPictures();
        Log.d(TAG, "position " + position);
        bm = pList.get(position - 1);
        Route routeDetail = list.get(position);
        RouteDetail fragment = new RouteDetail();
        fragment.loadData(routeDetail);
        fragment.loadPicture(bm);

        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.ticklist_container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

and the detail view:

```
package com.example.ticklist;

import com.example.ticklist.R;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RouteDetail extends Fragment{

    TextView routeName, routeGrade, routeDate, routeComments;
    ImageView img;
    private Route r;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route_detail,
            container, false);

        routeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.routeName);
        routeGrade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.routeGrade);
        routeDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.routeDate);
        routeComments = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.routeComments);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.routeImage);

        routeName.setText(r.getName());
        routeGrade.setText(r.getGrade());
        routeDate.setText(r.getDate());
        routeComments.setText(r.getComments());

        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        return view;
    }

    public void loadData(Route routeDetail) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.r = routeDetail;
    }
    public void loadPicture(Bitmap img){
        this.bmp = img;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bitmap doesn't HAVE to be compressed, but compressing them achieves two goals: It serializes them and it makes them smaller.

Bit maps are just .... maps of bits ... As trivial as it is, consider this:

If you had an image of 1000 x 1000, and each pixel represented a color using a short. (that's just an example, so roll with me). Now imagine that each pixel in this picture is WHITE.

If you serialized this without compressing then the file would store something like:
height:1000,width:1000,content:WHITE,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE,WHITE,.........

Serializing depends on the algorithm used, but let's say you use a variation of the LZW and use one int to indicate how many pixels are in the set and the color. In this case, all you had to save to the compressed file are height:1000,width:1000,content:1000000xWHITE. Which could be easily saved in a few bytes.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre. You answered my question. Can you then explain why my code above is not working? I know it's not the most efficient way of saving and loading an image, but why then can't I load the image on the RouteDetail fragment when I click on an item from "SendList"?

Comment: I am on my ipad, but you could see a serialization of bitmap here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871482/serializing-and-de-serializing-android-graphics-bitmap-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap is serializable (in fact bitmap IS a serialization). Just convert it to Base64.

So basically you can compress it, write it to a file or serialize it.

Comment: Thank you FeleMed. Just to be clear, are you saying Bitmap is serializable or that it can be serialized after compressing it? the docs say (as far as i understand) that it only implements parcelable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: I think he's saying that it's 'serializable' as in you can serialize it by converting it to Base64, but no, it doesn't actually implement Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be compressed, but saving them uncompressed is a very, very bad practice unless you have a specific reason not to.

The one advantage of Bitmaps - and the reason Android apps use them - is that they are completely uncompressed, essentially just an bunch of bits describing an image. Now, this means the format is incredibly simple and fast to decode, which is what makes them great for anything UI-oriented, including Android apps. If you were drawing, say, a PNG or a JPEG instead of a Bitmap, your app would be **much** slower.

However, this simplicity and complete lack of compression also makes it by far the **biggest** image format in terms of storage space used. Simply passing your Bitmap through even the least intrusive JPEG or PNG compressor will reduce the size by multiple orders of magnitude, at the cost of basically no quality (JPEG) or absolutely no loss of quality (PNG). This makes it pretty easy to understand why everyone does it, even if they don't have to. :)